# How to detect event for button DONE pressend on a Virtual Keyboard?

Tags: javascript, opera, virtual-keyboard, smart-tv

I need to capture an event when pressing DONE on a Virtual Keyboard on Opera Smart TV.
(If you know any other way to get an event key from JS apart what it here below, please let me know.)

With the following code I can get result for the key pressed on the virtual keyboard (ex: a, b, c..) but not the event for the button DONE. Even window.onkeydown does not fire

Any idea how to solve this?

```
    console.log(event.charCode);
            console.log(event.keyCode);
            window.onkeydown = keydown;
            function keydown() {
                alert("keydown event detected!");
            }
```

Comment: Looks like a serious problem. What does "Done" do? Maybe it triggers `submit` event?

Comment: DONE just close the keyboard, the focus remain on the input field. I do not have any form element on the page

Comment: In this case it probably doesn't dispatch any event at all (like when closing a native datepicker in Chrome). What are you trying to accomplish in general? Maybe we will came up with a workaround.

Comment: I need to set show/hide a div with some html when the keyboard is being hidden. DO you have any idea? Thanks for your time on this

Comment: Idk how advanced devtools on SmartTV's Opera are. With Chrome you can record Event Timeline while making some action and see what events was fired.

Comment: Thank Pavio, unfortunately Opera Smart TV emulator does not even emulate the virtual keyboard and on a real tv no way I could get the event :-(